# How should I apply this code to work with flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dateSection = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        DatePickerTimeline(
          DateTime.now(),
          onDateChange: (date) {
            // New date selected
            print(date.day.toString());
          },
        ),
      ],
```

---

#### The Problem is:

I just started coding

Pasting into flutter doesn't work.

How should I apply it to flutter?

What widgets should i  put in `DatePickerTimeline` ?

```
 DatePickerTimeline(
            this.currentDate, {
          Key key,
          this.width,
          this.height = 80,
          this.monthTextStyle = defaultMonthTextStyle,
          this.dayTextStyle = defaultDayTextStyle,
          this.dateTextStyle = defaultDateTextStyle,
          this.selectionColor = AppColors.defaultSelectionColor,
          this.daysCount = 50000,
          this.onDateChange,
          this.locale,
        }) : super(key: key);
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can declare a variable `_selectedValue` and set to `DateTime.now()`, then use it in `DatePickerTimeline`

code snippet

```
DateTime _selectedValue = DateTime.now();
...
DatePickerTimeline(
                    _selectedValue,
                    onDateChange: (date) {
                      // New date selected
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedValue = date;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Page1(title: 'Date Picker Timeline Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  DateTime _selectedValue = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("You Selected:"),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              ),
              Text(_selectedValue.toString()),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              ),
              DatePickerTimeline(
                _selectedValue,
                onDateChange: (date) {
                  // New date selected
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedValue = date;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```